# How we can describe entanglement from measurement and resource perspectives?

Tags: entanglement, teleportation, applications, superdense-coding

When we read books on quantum computing and information theory, specifically in entanglement we find some distinguishability between those who focus on entanglement as a resource or use it as an application  to explain some phenomenons (teleportation, superdense coding,..), and others study its measure (how long/far the state is still entangled) such as controlling satellites by sending entangled particles, because in this case entanglement could be affected by electromagnetic interactions and other factors of disturbance.

Could you please clarify this idea?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to [quantumcomputing.se]! Could you clarify what you mean by "use it (entanglement) as a unit measure of strength"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean its (entanglement) measure.
I don't know how to edit the question!

Comment: Click on [edit].